# can I assume downloading and using firefox portable on foreign computer keeps me private?

Tags: firefox, privacy, portable

Nothing so paranoid, but I just didn't like my history and any of my add-on/plugin installs will be visible on public computer after my use. I started using firefox portable, but because usb memory is from time to time blocked by policy I usually just fresh download it, do a install(well unzip in fact), use as I do on my pc (that is not using private mode to keep history within my browsing session intact), and delete entire folder permanently after I use.
  Am I right to assume that unless someone goes paranoid to recover dead files I'm keeping myself clean of remnants of my search history, extension installs, etc.?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on which folder you are deleting - Firefox portable uses this lcoation to store data:

Drive>: \PortableApps \FirefoxPortable \Data \profile

So if you are deleting the FirefoxPortable with all of its subdirectories you should be OK.

However restoring deleted files is fairly simple so I would use some online anonymizing service on top of what you are doing

Comment: Yup I do delete FirefoxPortable folder (I download FF portable separately, not portableapps bundle)
Yes I understand restoring files is relatively easy but at least my trace won't be visible everywhere unless someone decides to do investigation...correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: @user287147: You could probably also use something like [Eraser Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/security/eraser-portable) to securely delete the folder and files.

Comment: BTW if you are satisfied with an answer it is great to accept it and vote it up - it helps to close the Qs and keep it clean

Comment: done. thx for comment.